# How to get the value of any column of a row inserted with JdbcTemplate

Tags: postgresql, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

Can I use Spring's `JdbcTemplate` to get a column value of a row just inserted?

E.g. the SQL looks so:

```
insert into table1 (name, age) values ('name', 20) returning name;
```

And I want to get the value of the `name` column.

The `update()` method returns the number of inserted rows only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you can insert rows if you use `JdbcTemplate.queryForObject()` and the sql uses `with ... as` construct:

```
String sql="with result as (\n" +
        "insert into table1 (name, age) values ('name', 20) returning name\n" +
        ")\n" +
        "select name from result;";

String name = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, String.class);
```